# Keeping Scanner running/listening in main method (two threads)

Tags: java, multithreading

problem description:

Modify these files to be able to interactively ask the user to supply the advertisement message to be shown.  The user types in the message to be displayed and presses the ENTER key.  Accept the message that the user entered.  Show the message that the user requested as the advertisement message, repeatedly with a pause of 1 second between displays.

If the user presses ENTER again (while the previous message is being displayed), the program should ask the user for a new (modified) message.  The user types in a new message and presses the ENTER key.  The advertisement display should now change to show the new message display, repeatedly with a pause of 1 second between displays.  Exit the program when the user enters n (case-insensitive).

If I use the following code, the first time I enter a message it works properly and when I hit enter, the repeated printing of the message is interrupted correctly and I am prompted to enter a new message.  however, when I click enter the repeated printing is not interrupted because the main method has completed:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Advertisement extends Thread
{
    private boolean done = false;
    String message = "";
    public void run()
    {
        Thread myThread = Thread.currentThread();
        while (!isDone())
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter the advertisement message to be displayed   
                   (enter 'n' to exit):");
            Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            message = sc2.nextLine();
            if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
            {
                done = true;
                System.out.println("User Stopped the Message Output");
                continue;
            }

            while (!(myThread.isInterrupted()))
            {
                try
                {
                    System.out.print("** " + message + " **");
                    myThread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {  
                    System.out.println("Exception caught: " + e.getMessage());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }// end of 'run()' ..
    /**
     * @return the done
     */
    public boolean isDone()
    {
        return done;
    }
```

}

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestAdvt2
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Advertisement advt = new Advertisement();
        advt.start();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str = "start";
        while (!((str.equals(""))))
        {
            str = sc.nextLine();
        }
        advt.interrupt();
    }
}
```

If I change the main method to include a while loop, then the interrupt stops working completely.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class TestAdvt
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Advertisement advt = new Advertisement();
        advt.start();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean done = false;
        while (done == false);
        {
            String str = "start";
            while (!((str.equals(""))))
            {
                str = sc.nextLine();
            }
            done = advt.isDone();
            advt.interrupt();
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on how to get this working so that the message can be changed would be appreciated.

Jeanne

UPDATE:

I was able to use your suggestions to fix my code.  I needed to do some cleanup and use the synchronized keyword instead of the volatile keyword (which is what the teacher wanted).

Here is the fixed code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
*
* @author Jeanne Gaskill
*/

public class Advertisement2 extends Thread
{
    private boolean done = false;
    String message = "";

    public void run() 
    {
        Thread myThread = Thread.currentThread();
        while (true) 
        {
            while (!done) 
            {
                System.out.println("\n\nPlease enter the advertisement message to be displayed "
                    + "(type message or enter 'n' to exit):\n");
                Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                message = sc2.nextLine();
                done = true;
                System.out.println("\n");
                if (message.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) 
                    {
                        System.out.println("User Stopped the Message Output");
                        // Terminating
                        System.exit(0);
                        continue;
                    }
                while (!(myThread.isInterrupted())) 
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        System.out.print("** " + message + " **");
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } 
                    catch (InterruptedException e) 
                    {
                        // System.out.println("Exception caught: " + e.getMessage());
                        done = false;
                        break;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }// end of 'run()' ..

    /**
    * @return  done variable
    */
    synchronized public boolean isDone() 
    {
        return done;
    }    

    /**
     * @param done  to set done variable
     */
    synchronized public void setDone(boolean done)
    {
        this.done = done;
    }
```

}

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestAdvt
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {    
        Advertisement advt = new Advertisement();
        advt.start();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) 
        {
            while (advt.isDone()) 
            {
                // main thread is listening
                String str = sc.nextLine();

                // check for new line
                if (str.equals("")) 
                {
                    advt.interrupt();
                }
                advt.setDone(false);
            }
        }
    }
```

}

@Jigar

Thanks again!

Comment: You want something like this http://ideone.com/eEb10q format, understand and cleanup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

couple of things in your code

- you need to keep listening on main only when Advertisement Thread isn't listening and when it is just printing
- You need to use `volatile` for flag variable
- control the flag properly

in summary [this is the code you need](http://ideone.com/eEb10q), format, cleanup, is on your side